# Connect to gatt server not working on Samsung Galaxy Core Prime (Android 5.1.1)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I have a BLE app which works on devices with Android 6.0 and higher but I have issues on Samsung Galaxy Core Prime (Android 5.1.1). After calling `connectGatt` nothing happens and the callback receives only disconnected state.

I have cut out appropriate code:

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
final BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
Log.e("BluetoothLeService", "connect: connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback)");
BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);

private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Log.e("BluetoothLeService", "onConnectionStateChange: STATE_CONNECTED");
        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.e("BluetoothLeService", "onConnectionStateChange: STATE_DISCONNECTED");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMtuChanged (BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status) {
    }
};
```

And here is the log:

```
E/BluetoothLeService: connect: connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback)
I/StatusBar: Icon Only
D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: CC:4B:73:22:9D:DB, auto: false
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=7d428718-b549-4021-8a45-9d3bd2afd462
D/BtGatt.GattService: registerClient() - UUID=7d428718-b549-4021-8a45-9d3bd2afd462
D/SamsungIME: Dismiss ExpandCandiate
D/PanelView: There is/are notification(s) 
D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1248000  uid : 1000  pid : 2975  tag : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@4
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{2bfa99a5 u0 com.streamunlimited.streamsdkdemo/.ui.setup.SetupDeviceActivity t43} time:3838458
W/ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.release()
D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1248000  uid : 1000  pid : 2975  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@8
D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientRegistered() - UUID=7d428718-b549-4021-8a45-9d3bd2afd462, clientIf=6
D/BluetoothLeService: Trying to create a new connection.
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
D/BtGatt.GattService: clientConnect() - address=CC:4B:73:22:9D:DB, isDirect=true set own addr = false own addr type:0
D/BtGatt.btif: btif_get_device_type: Device [cc:4b:73:22:9d:db] type 3, addr. type 0
D/IOP_DB_BT: db_query_create: id EnforceMasterRole :: key KEY_BDADDR, value cc:4b:73:22:9d:db
D/IOP_DB_BT: db_query_add_key: key KEY_LMP_MFCT, value 15
D/IOP_DB_BT: db_query_add_key: key KEY_LMP_VER, value 9:24838
D/IOP_DB_BT: db_query_add_key: key KEY_DIR_ALL, value 1
D/IOP_DB_BT: db_query_execute: result 1
D/bluedroid-mrvl: bt_vnd_mrvl_if_op(L95): opcode = 7
I/SurfaceFlinger: id=153 Removed TetupScanAc (3/9)
I/SurfaceFlinger: id=153 Removed TetupScanAc (-2/9)
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@21558ec5 time:3838516
W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
D/CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1248000  uid : 1000  pid : 2975  tag : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@8
D/BatteryService: !@BatteryListener : batteryPropertiesChanged!
W/bt-btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=4 connected=0 conn_id=4 reason=0x0004
W/bt-btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=5 connected=0 conn_id=5 reason=0x0004
W/bt-btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=6 connected=0 conn_id=6 reason=0x0004
D/BtGatt.GattService: onConnected() - clientIf=6, connId=0, address=CC:4B:73:22:9D:DB
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=6 device=CC:4B:73:22:9D:DB
E/BluetoothLeService: onConnectionStateChange: STATE_DISCONNECTED
```

The lines that look suspicious are:

```
W/bt-btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=4 connected=0 conn_id=4 reason=0x0004
W/bt-btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=5 connected=0 conn_id=5 reason=0x0004
W/bt-btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=6 connected=0 conn_id=6 reason=0x0004
```

I found that reason 4 means:

```
PAGE TIMEOUT (0x04)
The Page Timeout error code indicates that a page timed out because of the
Page Timeout configuration parameter. This error code may occur only with the
Remote_Name_Request and Create_Connection commands.
```

in documentation https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=421043&_ga=2.243934277.1321770839.1542020684-854809025.1539785109

Also this line:

```
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=6 device=CC:4B:73:22:9D:DB
```

is just a macro for GATT_ERROR based on:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-4.4.4_r2.0.1/stack/include/gatt_api.h

I have also tried nRF Connect app and it fails to connect too with: Error 133 (0x85):GATT ERROR

Do you know any possible reason and solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: Im pretty sure it is samsung just being stupid in general. Had the same issue in projects that I made for the company I work for. We ended up retrying to connect a couple times in a row cause it is the same things the NRFConnect folks did. There is an issue on their github somewhere. And well they are Nordic folks who make BLE ICs. Apparently samsung has issues with internal service cache refreshing, so you can also hack a method that is private and call it via reflection and it apparently solves it. We chose to just connect a couple times in a row.

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić Thanks for you advice.
So you say that I should try to call `device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);` when I receive disconnect call `device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);` till I get connected or max number of tries is reached?
Any advice on that max number of retries? Thanks

Comment: We used 5 retries, but make sure you check that the disconnect error is 133

Answer (score 2):

Error status 133 may have various reasons as it is a general error reported by the Android system. Possible causes:

1. When the peripheral is out of range / turned off at the moment of establishing 
   the connection
2. When the Android BLE stack is not working correctly (sometimes turning off and on both Bluetooth Adapter and WiFi helps)
3. When a peripheral does not conform correctly to BLE specification
4. When the phone BLE drivers are not good enough
5. Other (check google)

The easiest workaround, is to retry to connect if it fails with that type of error.

I highly recommend using [Polidea's RxAndroidBle Library](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) for implementing BLE communication, it is very useful.

If you start using it, then you can try to establish the connection and then retry  if it fails using a the operator `retryWhen`. [You can get some clues in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43783212/10648865).